# Download file from Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

Have multiple blobs, have extracted the name of each blob into a list, with its last modified date. 
Have set a download path, and then run the following code, where the kvp.Key is the name of each blob. The idea being I can loop round each file name and download it:

```
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DateTimeOffset?> kvp in to_be_dl)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading: " + kvp.Key);

            //Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key+" "+kvp.Value);
            foreach (CloudBlockBlob blobItem in blobs)
            {

                    try
                    {
                        blobItem.DownloadToFile(downloadpath + "\\" + kvp.Key, FileMode.Create);
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                        break;
                    }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Downloaded: " + kvp.Key);
        }
```

Is there a way to be able to get a blob by its name and download the corresponding file?

Comment: What is `kvp.Key` in your code? I don't see it changing for each blob.

Comment: Sorry, didn't make that clear. It is a nested foreach, kvp is a key value pair which holds the file name, and last modified date. So the kvp.Key is the file name I have extracted from each blob. When debugging, this file name does change for each loop.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. So if I understand correctly, multiple zip files are downloaded and when you extract each zip file they all contain same files. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I have been debugging the code, and it appears that the blobItem does not move to the file name. Is there a way I can tell it which blobItem I want to download with the kvp.Key (filename) I have?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and share the complete code? Obviously, remove the storage credentials and other sensitive information from your code before posting it here.

Comment: Edited the question. The issue I have I think is, I am not able to get the blob by its name. Is there a way of getting the blob by its name? Thanks for your assistance with this, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a flaw in your logic :).

Essentially your outer loop gets the name of the downloaded file but then your inner loop iterates over the blobs and then downloads each blob with the same name set in the outer loop.

What that does is that it saves the last blob (or the first blob) in the inner loop multiple times with different names.

That's why when you unzip the files, you get the same content even though the file name is different because the same blob gets downloaded (even though saved with a different name).

To solve this problem, what you can do is create an instance of `CloudBlockBlob` using the `Key` in your `kvp` and then try to download that blob. Something like below:

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DateTimeOffset?> kvp in to_be_dl)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading: " + kvp.Key);
            var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(kvp.Key);
            try
            {
                //If the blob doesn't exist, you will get an error and then your code should move to the next key
                blob.DownloadToFile(downloadpath + "\\" + kvp.Key, FileMode.Create);
                Console.WriteLine("Downloaded: " + kvp.Key);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to download: " + kvp.Key);
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks - I see, a stupid mistake! Is there a way of being able to get a blob by the blob name? Therefore setting the blob I want by the name I have in the key value pair and matching the two? Thanks for your help.

Comment: CloudBlockBlob has a property called `Name` and that will give you the name of the blob. Is your key name same as blob's name? If that is the case then you could wrap your download code inside an `if` block. Something like `if (blob.Name == kvp.Key) { blobItem.DownloadToFile(downloadpath + "\\" + kvp.Key, FileMode.Create); }`.

Comment: Yes, I have another method that goes to the blobs and gets the name of each and returns them in a list. I am then using that list to populate kvp.

Comment: Thank you! That has solved it, GetBlockBlobReference was what I needed!